# Don't remember a book: Merlin/Grey Side

Tags: story-identification

There was a book I've read a long time ago about someone related to Merlin or something and his travel to another world that was separated into 3 sides - grey, dark and light.

He also could use an artifact that can do anything. The book name said something about Merlin and grey side, although I'm not sure about that. Can someone help me? This have been bugging me for a while now.

I also remember some parts of the plot like the boy was in school and he was bullied (maybe?) but he was transported into the world by someone else and he changed his race? I also remember a vampire castle and vampire lions for some reason.

Edit. If i am not mistaken, part of the story (the beginning) was set in modern (relatively) time.

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Possibly [The Dark is Rising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Is_Rising_Sequence)?

Comment: I just checked, i don't think it is The Dark is Rsing

Comment: Roughly how long ago?

Comment: Around, i would say, 10 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

This might be pushing it, but if I tweak some of your criteria...  Does *The Lost Years of Merlin* sound familiar?

The book was originally published in 1996, though republished a few times with different covers.  The first of a 5-book trilogy, the series later became the first arc of the *Merlin Saga* and was republished with its newest cover in 2011, close to when you remember.  Below are the 1999 and 2011 covers, it's likely one of these two is what you read if this is the book:

[image: The Lost Years of Merlin, 1999 cover][image: The Lost Years of Merlin, 2011 cover]

Comparison points:

- Another world, separated into grey/dark/light - Aside from the introductory chapters, the series takes place on the isle of Fincayra, said to exist halfway between Earth and the Otherworld.  Various comparisons are made over the course of the series, like day/night/twilight and air/water/mist.  The phrase "in-between place" is used often and may spark a memory.
- Had an artifact that could do anything - This could be the Galator, the green jewel in the first cover above.  It was said to have great power, it aided his grandfather in defeating the greatest dragon in history, and was sought after by many.  But he never learned how to use it.
- Boy was in school and bullied - Not in school, but Merlin was a bully magnet before leaving home and finding Fincayra.  Among other things, the other kids called him a demon because of his slightly pointed ears.
- Changed his race - Discovered that native Fincayran humans all have pointed ears.
- Vampire castle/lions - This is really stretching it, but this first book did have a castle that rotated on its base, that was guarded by "deathless Ghouliants".

Comment: I've looked at the description and read through 1st chapter quickly but it doesn't seems to be the one.

Comment: @VladislavChoulgénko Yeah, that modern-time addition to the question definitely doesn't fit